# How to call TapGestureRecognizer from ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, xamarin.forms, gesture-recognition

I'm trying to implement TapGestureRecognizer which will be called in ViewModel (xaml.cs) not in View class...

Here is sample code in xaml file: (IrrigNetPage.xaml)

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:i18n="clr-namespace:agroNet.AppResource;assembly=agroNet"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:agroNet.ViewModel"
         x:Class="agroNet.View.IrrigNetPage"
         BackgroundColor="#EBEBEB">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="HideListOnTap"/>
        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    </Grid>
```

I implemented HideListOnTap in xaml.cs page (view) like this: (IrrigNetPage.xaml.cs)

```
    int visibility = 1;
    private void HideListOnTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        visibility++;
        if ((visibility % 2) == 0)
        {
            IrrigList.IsVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            IrrigList.IsVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

It's working fine, but how to do the same thing usin ViewModel?
(How to bind Gesture recognizer from (IrrigNetPage.xaml) with HideListOnTap in IrrigNetViewModel )

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/tap#using-icommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [Command](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/simplifying-events-with-commanding/) whenever you want to handle some event in the ViewModel. Without passing any arguments the code would look like as follows

```
<!-- in IrrigNetPage.xaml -->

<TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding HideListOnTapCommand}"/>
```

And in the ViewModel IrrigNetPageViewModel.cs

```
public ICommand HideListOnTapCommand { get; } 

public IrrigNetPageViewModel()
{
   HideListOnTapCommand = new Command(HideListOnTap); 
   // if HideListOnTap is async create your command like this
   // HideListOnTapCommand = new Command(async() => await HideListOnTap());

}

private void HideListOnTap()
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer...
`IrrigList` is x:name of ListView in IrrigNetPage.xaml, so I still have problem, because "The name 'IrrigList' does not exist in the current context". Is there any solution how to do the same thing without x:name?

Comment: This answer is 100% the right and full answer to your original problem, please mark it as correct. I understand that this now gives another problem, since `IrrigList` exists on your page and not your viewmodel. Search for CommandParameter. You can solve your new problem by passing your `IrrigList` as `CommandParameter`. Will look something like this: `CommandParameter={x:Reference IrrigList}`. Keep in mind you still have to change your command to use a parameter.

Comment: @Knoop Could you, please, show me how to change command, then?

Comment: So you are saying you need now access to your ListView within your ViewModel? This contradicts the MVVM philosophy. Instead of accessing the whole model instead bind the properties you want to change within your model. E.g. add a IsListVisible property to your viewmodel and bind the ListView's Visiblility attribute to this property. Don't forget these properties need to fire a NotifyPropertyChanged event so the View picks up on the change